# Seaborn heatmap throws "isnan" type of error after update

Tags: python, seaborn

I've been recently dealing with heatmaps in Python, more specifically, I've been drawing with the seaborn library. Up to some point, everything worked perfectly, my snippet looked something like:

```
result = df.pivot(index='indexcol', columns='coltwo', values='hvalues')
ax = sns.heatmap(result, cbar=False, yticklabels=True, xticklabels=True, linewidths=.1, cmap=ListedColormap(['white', 'green', 'red']))
plt.show()
```

where my result is a Pandas dataframe. After I updated to 0.8.2, it started to throw something like:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I can fix this partially, by using `result.astype(int)` in the heatmap call, yet the plots do not look the same.

Apart from a downgrade, what options do I have?

Comment: The best option you have is to provide a [mcve] of the issue - just as usual, when inquiring about undesired code behaviours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved this with:

```
result.fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

a row before the heatmap plot. The problem was, that the new seaborn couldn't handle None, yet numpy nan is apparently ok.